# Talking to supervisor about PhD projects

Tags: advisor, career-path, supervision, early-career, research-topic

I am an international PhD student, in the last lap of my PhD, and have a little more than a year to defend my thesis. My work is in theory, and our simulations take a lot of computing time. As we are working on wrapping up my first paper now, I want to only focus on projects which will lead to publications since our Faculty requires 4 papers(published and/or submitted to journals) to be able to defend one's thesis. I have tried to talk to my supervisor about this, but he only spared 13 minutes listening to the project ideas I have had and did not get involved with ideas or give any input.
I am guessing there is a bias how he handles my involvement in his projects since a relatively new PhD student(who is a local and have been in the department since his Bachelor's) receive a lot of his attention. It is not about that my supervisor should be more involved in my prospects, but at least he should give it as much attention as any other. He also holds many other positions, one of them being department head and trying to solve a serious work-environment issue in the department in a different group. So he remains quite busy in meetings since the last few months.

So, what should be my way of communicating my career prospects in the year to come with him and my team so that we can work towards achieving them in a specific time frame? I do lack the field-insights which my team has and in that respect, they can help me a lot to plan efficiently.

Comment: Some supervisors are more interested in the "new" projects, like readers are in the newspaper of today, not yesterday. Especially if they are overloaded with admin duties, they need something to take their mind off it, and it's most likely that a project that is fresh has more "refreshment value" than a project that is several years old. In other words: it does not have to have to do with you in particular, rather with the novelty value. Try to set up fixed slots, half-hour if an hour is too much, with a clear agenda for your supervisor. Help him supervise you.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs can you move your comment as an answer to this? I really found it helpful and it is one of the solutions to my query.

Comment: Transformed into an answer, as per your suggestion. I didn't expect it be answer-quality, but if it helped you, it clearly elevates it to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some supervisors are more interested in the "new" projects, like readers are in the newspaper of today, not yesterday.

Especially if they are overloaded with admin duties, they need something to take their mind off it, and it's most likely that a project that is fresh has more "refreshment value" than a project that is several years old.

In other words: it does not have to have to do with you in particular, rather with the novelty value of your work vs. the new student's work.

So my advice is: try to set up fixed slots, even just half-hour, if an hour is too much, preparing a clear agenda ahead of time for your supervisor. Help him supervise you.

Answer (score 0):

These 13 minutes of which you speak, was that a meeting that you planned in advance? Or did you happen to meet him at a random moment? If it was a planned meeting, you should insist on another planned meeting of at least an hour to discuss this point and only this point. If it was a random moment, your supervisor might already be late for another urgent appointment.

Comment: To extend this a bit... definitely try to schedule time with your advisor well in advance and at a time of his convenience. Additionally, make sure to speak with the team before talking with your advisor, as you indicate that they may be able to help you refine your ideas.

Answer (score -2):

You have less than a year to defend your thesis. You haven't published anything and need four publications before you can defend. Publishing four papers in a year is problematic: You have to write the papers, submit them, and wait for reviews. Can you manage that four times in the time you have? If so, great, go do it. Otherwise, speak to your supervisor about an extension.

Discussing new project ideas with less than a year surely isn't a viable way to finish on time. You need to focus on work that's nearly complete. If you don't have such work, speak to your supervisor about an extension.

I don't agree that your supervisor should give you as much time as other students. All students deserve a certain level of supervision. This level will vary as a student progresses: New students need more attention than older students. A supervisor may go above-and-beyond for some students at their discretion, likely benefiting better students, who significantly further the supervisor's interests.

Comment: "Better students deserve more attention than weaker students. " I think that is a poor work ethic issue, quite opposite to being an effective way of working. Once a PhD becomes a part of a research group, it is a joint project until the completion of the thesis.

Comment: @tachyon I disagree. Supervision is both an investment and a commitment. Some students should be asked to leave, if they cannot deliver on their duties. The strongest should get additional time, if useful. Ultimately, supervisors have duties too. PhD students help them fulfil those duties. Time must be distributed to ensure better returns.

Comment: there seems to be a fundamental difference between academic employment terms in your place of work and the country where I am working in. Our University cannot  ask a student to leave without serious charges against them. PhDs and PIs all have demarcated duties, responsibilities and goals which get revised every semester. Hence a problem in productivity is easily tracked months, sometimes years before it becomes a problem. One can also change supervisor if it is not working out with the current supervisor, for example.

Comment: Put another way, suppose you have some projects. Some doing well, some reasonable, some bad, and others failing. Time committed to failing projects can be a waste of time, abandoning them might be better. Turning around a bad project might be worthwhile, there's a judgement call. Time needs to be committed to projects that are going reasonable well, to ensure they continue doing so, or better. Time committed to projects that are doing well might boost them to doing great, which might be a worthy investment. It's difficult.

Comment: @tachyon It isn't about academic employment terms, it's about success. For success, a supervisor needs great team members, they'll likely deliver more than the rest of the team. The department needs successful supervisors, even if this means some students under perform. Ultimately, departments need not concern themselves with employment terms, because they aren't responsible for student success, the student is. Is that fair? Well, the department wants to succeed, as do supervisors, and so do students, so the system is fair in increasing success.

Comment: @user2768 I may agree with "Older students need less supervision than newer students." I do not agree with "Better students deserve more attention than weaker students" unless the student has really failed to apply themselves, become antagonistic, or are just lazying off. Once the superviser has accepted the student, they are co-responsible for the student's success. Of course, they cannot compensate everything, but it is a very cynical view to drop a student because they are not as successful. A wrong project direction can easily hold a good student back and make the "effectively" weaker.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Investors walk away from bad investments, supervisors fail bad students. Investors double-down on good investors and reduce their effort on weaker ones, they maintain any commitment, but they don't go beyond. A rational supervisor surely behaves the same, to a lesser degree: They don't go above-and-beyond for students that they feel aren't fulfilling their duty.

Comment: @user2768 "maintain any committment" is something quite different from "walk away from bad investment". The latter sounds cynical, I am sorry to say. Of course, not everybody ultimately succeeds in getting a PhD. But there needs to be a serious good faith effort to get a student once one has accepted them as a PhD student and who might spend more time on your research project than in their whole studies, to get them through. Some compare a supervision to a mini-marriage or -adoption. Of course, things can sour. But if a supervisor finds oneself dumping students, they should select better.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Don't we have a duty to fail students that cannot succeed? We certainly have a duty to do our best, but, ultimately, not everyone can get a PhD.

Comment: @user2768 Yes. But the selection *ahead of time* for a PhD needs to be so careful that a failure will very rarely happen. I consider a failure at PhD level to a significant degree a failure of the supervisor, especially their vetting of the candidates.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I don't disagree. Yet, many universities have mechanisms in place to ensure suitable progression of students and don't allow flagging students to proceed. This isn't ideal, but it does serve the interests of students, supervisors, and universities.

Comment: @user2768 All agreed, and we have that, too. I was just quite concerned about your formulations that came across as if less successful students are essentially sidelined. One special problem with PhDs as opposed to undergrad and Masters is that it is not necessarily the student that is weaker, but the problem that is harder. This makes such tiering particularly prone to unfairness.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs _I was just quite concerned about your formulations that came across as if less successful students are essentially sidelined_: Perhaps poor communication/fatigue/laziness on my part. I believe all students deserve a certain level of supervision. A supervisor may go beyond that level at their discretion, in particular, a supervisor may go above-and-beyond for students with mutually aligned interests.